# make checkbox display the same as an input

Tags: html, css

i have created this fiddle with my HTML and css code on

https://jsfiddle.net/1u2632sL/1/

The text inputs are displaying correctly, but i want to be able to have the checkboxes display inline with their labels too

i used this for the inputs css:

```
.form-field input, .form-field select {
    min-width:250px;
    height:30px;
    color:#F36F25;
}
```

but its not working the same for the checkbox inputs

Comment: I am not sure to understand what you want. Do you want the label of the checkbox to be vertically centered with the checkbox ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give height `auto` to the check box.

Here is the example

```css
.form-field {
 margin-bottom:10px;
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
}
.form-field input, .form-field select {
 min-width:250px;
 height:30px;
 color:#F36F25;
}
.form-label {
 float:left;
 min-width:200px;
}
input[type='checkbox']{
 heigh: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-field">
<label>Checkbox 1</label>
<input type="checkbox">
</div>

<div class="form-field">
<label>Input 1</label>
<input type="input">
</div>
```

Here is the updated [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/1u2632sL/5/)

Answer (score 1):

Please try this...

```css
.form-field {
 margin-bottom:10px;
}
.form-field input[type="text"], .form-field select {
 min-width:250px;
 height:30px;
 color:#F36F25;
}
.form-field input[type="checkbox"] { width:50px; height:30px; }
.form-label {
 float:left;
 min-width:200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-field">
<label>Checkbox 1</label>
<input type="checkbox">
</div>

<div class="form-field">
<label>Input 1</label>
<input type="text">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the min-width to 40px. That will display the checkbox next to its label.

Answer (score 0):

Your styles for your text input were interfering with your checkbox styles.

It's best if you specify the input styles to the correct type using `input[type='checkbox']` and `input[type='input']`. This way, you won't have conflicting styles between your inputs.

**CSS**

```
.form-field input[type='input'] {
  min-width:250px;
  height:30px;
  color:#F36F25;
}
.form-field input[type='checkbox'] {
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

**Result**

[image]

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1u2632sL/4/)**

Answer (score -1):

I just changed your input css to this:

```
.form-field input, .form-field select {
    color:#F36F25;
}
```

And the checkbox was displayed next to the label: https://jsfiddle.net/1u2632sL/2/